# I faced some problems to enhance on multiple images using Python, It shows some error

Tags: python, spyder, image-preprocessing

Here, I want to change the default sharpness of the image dataset. It works fine for a single image, but when I apply on multiple images, it shows me an error like **AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'filter'**. What should I do to fix this? To that end, my code is given below-

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
import cv2
import glob

dataset = glob.glob('input/*.png')
other_dir = 'output/'
for img_id, img_path in enumerate(dataset):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)

    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img)
    enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(8.0)

    cl2 = cv2.resize(enhanced_im, (1024,1024), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{other_dir}/enhanced_{img_id}.png',cl2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `PIL` to enhance a `numpy` array. `cv2` converts images from image paths into `numpy` arrays. This doesn't work with `PIL` image operations.

You can load the image using `PIL`, do the `PIL` enhancements then convert it to a numpy array to pass into your `cv2.resize()` method.

Try:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

dataset = glob.glob('input/*.png')
other_dir = 'output/'
for img_id, img_path in enumerate(dataset):
    img = Image.open(img_path)  # this is a PIL image

    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(img)  # PIL wants its own image format here
    enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(8.0)  # and here
    enhanced_cv_im = np.array(enhanced_im) # cv2 wants a numpy array

    cl2 = cv2.resize(enhanced_cv_im, (1024,1024), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{other_dir}/enhanced_{img_id}.png',cl2)
```